# ¿Cómo configurar Nginx para despliegue de aplicación con el Stack MERN con certificado SSL (Certbot)?

Tags: nginx, certificado-ssl

Hola tengo una aplicación desarrollada con React para el Frontend y Node-Express-MongoDB para el Backend,
al desplegarla (usando DigitalOcean), funciona sin problema... Hasta que quise incorporarle un certificado SSL (usando Certbot y Nginx)...
La aplicación (Frontend) se ejecuta, pero cuando realiza alguna petición Backend (por API REST), no consigo respuesta...
Por lo que he investigado es porque el cliente emite la petición como HTTPS y el backend esta en HTTP... Y he tratado de configurar Nginx sin exito...

Si alguien me puede orientar o guiarme como configurar nginx, se lo agradecería mucho...

Dejo una imagen de como entiendo que debería ser la solución... Favor corregir si me equivoco...

[image: Ejemplo de interacción servidores]

Esta es la configuración por defecto al instalar Certbot con Nginx

```js
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.dominio.com dominio.com; # managed by Certbot
  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass \$http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host\$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.dominio.com dominio.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

De antemano, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo por tus requerimientos que necesitas un proxy inverso, se conoce como proxy inverso, cuando un servidor (en este caso, Nginx HTTP) acepta todo el tráfico y lo reenvía a un recurso específico, por ejemplo a un servidor Apache.

Los motivos para instalar y usar un servidor proxy son muchos. Por ejemplo, un proxy inverso permite agregar seguridad al servidor principal (HTTPS) y reenviar el trafico a un servidor (HTTP) que es tu caso, también se utiliza para equilibrar la carga, restringir el acceso a rutas definidas, permite evitar ataques, etc…

La implementacion es muy particular debido a cada entorno, por lo tanto te dejo un ejemplo de lo que deberia ser tu archivo de configuracion y algunos enlaces de orientación.

Documentación oficial NGINX: [Mira el enalce](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Documentacion oficial de Digital Ocean: [Mira el enlace](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-nginx-como-servidor-web-y-proxy-inverso-para-apache-en-un-servidor-ubuntu-18-04-es)

Modelo de archivo de configuración:

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;

    root /var/www/dominio.com/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com;
    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


    location /back {
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3001/back;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        expires 0m;
    }

    location /front {
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080/front;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        expires 0m;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Jorge!! Gracias por la respuesta... Estoy probando lo que me dices... aún no me ha funcionado... pero creo que va por ahí... Ahora tengo que ver como hacer que el frontend lo tome con el "/front" o similar... ya que previamente lo tenía "/"... y al ingresar el "/" y "/back" o similar... me da error en sintaxis del nginx...Veré como cambiarlo y te comento...

Comment: El location /front y /back son location que te puse de ejemplo ya que no sabemos cual es la ruta de tu API, lo hice de esa forma para diferenciarlos porque van a puertos diferentes. Suerte! Recuerda ponderar la respuesta si ha sido de tu utilidad. Saludos!